# Fine-tuning T5 model using Tensor-flow

Tags: neural-network, classification, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers, fine-tuning

I finetuned the T5 using tensorflow to do text classification and when used the model summary this is the plot here [model-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urkbW.png). Is it correct ?

why input of the model not appear in this plot ?